Storage file are deleted on ssh server after running git checkout
There are files are deleted from my project on ssh server, after server failure I tried to recover by running
> git checkout .

on a folder contains storage files are stored on the server not on the github repository.
I am looking for a solution to recover the lost files.
Please your help!

This question is similar to: How to recover deleted files?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
